# Your iPhone is not available. Please select a different device and try again

Tags: ios, xcode, watchos-2

I'm getting the following error when I try to build my Watch OS 2 app on my iPhone (iOS 9.0b2) which is paired to my Apple Watch (watchOS 2.0b2).

> Your iPhone is not available. Please select a different device and try again.

I've tried all the obvious things, restarting iPhone, Watch, Mac, etc. All my software is updated to the latest version and my watch is paired to my iPhone. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I'm not familiar with watchkit, but maybe its a problem with 1. Your devices being provisioned in the Xcode organizer 2. the app's app id 3. the bundle identifier.

Comment: I have the same problem , do you solve it , thanks

Answer (score 7):

Connect the phone and open iTunes.  Once the "Trust this iPhone" sequence is complete via iTunes, the phone will be recognized in Xcode.

Comment: This did it for mine

Comment: correct answer.

Comment: Did not work for me

Comment: Hm, doesn't open "Trust this iPhone" for me when I open iTunes 

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I resolved the issue.

1) Disconnect your iPhone device out of your laptop completely.

2) Close Xcode and launch it back up again.

3) Wait till Xcode finish indexing

4) Choose a different scheme (say *YourProject*Test scheme) and one of your iPhone simulators.

5) Clean one more time, Build, and then Run your app.

6) Now connect your device, switch Schemes back to the original (*YourProject* scheme), and choose your specific device you just connected to run your app on.

7) Run the app and you should be golden.